# Windows freezes when watching videos

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, freeze

I have Acer laptop Aspire 5740 - 5780 with windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit.
I am using Chrome. Windows is 1 year old, but it's not the
first time this has happened.

Windows freezes whenever I am watching videos on facebook/youtube
or when using SopCast. I thought there was some faulty plugin, so I recently
re-installed chrome but it happened again.
No keys work, and the sound of whatever I am listening starts repeating like
grrrr..drrrr. Its seems like the sound in very slow motion.
One time I left it in this freeze state for 5 min and it recovered automatically.
It usually does not happen when I am using windows media player. I had some
codecs installed but I removed them to see if that fixes. So far, I have narrowed
it down to youtube/footytube videos and sopcast.

I have checked event logs but nothing special. Is there any way I can narrow down
the problem or any suggestions on how to fix it.

I'd like to add that it does not always happen. Sometimes windows goes days/weeks without freezing, and sometimes it take a min into video to freeze.

Answer (score 1):

This should help.
Rigth click on video and try disabling hardware acceleration.

[image: HW]

Comment: @cornerback84 Im glad I could help.